# grouping multiple criteria with mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a data table that is structured like the one below.

```
DATE      ORDER_NUMBER  PROMO_CODE
1/1/2015  O1            P1
1/1/2015  O2            P1
1/1/2015  O3            P2
1/2/2015  O4            P1
1/2/2015  O5            P3
```

Is there a MySQL query I can execute to get a table that groups by date as the rows and a count of each promo code used as the columns? The output that I'm looking for would look like this:

```
DATE      P1  P2  P3
1/1/2015  2   1   0
1/2/2015  0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple group by query:

```
select DATE, count(PROMO_CODE) from yourtable group by DATE;
```

Comment: I tried this and I can get the count grouped by date. Do you know of a way I could get the counts for each unique promo code in addition to the date?

So for example I would have a row for 1/1/2015 and my counts for P1, P2, and P3.

Answer (score 0):

If you [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) your query, you can then count everything that has the same `DATE`:

```
SELECT DATE, count(PROMO_CODE) 
FROM order_table 
GROUP BY (DATE);
```